# sns開発時の注意点

Tags: webapi

現在snsのようなものを製作しています。画像をアップロードできるようにしようとおもっています。そこで、児童ポルノ、せいきの画像をアップロードされ、サーバーに保存した場合、利用規約で禁止していてもサーバー所持者は逮捕されてしまうのでしょうか。される場合回避方などあれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 微妙なラインなのですが、このサイトでは適法かどうか判断が求められるような質問は募集している質問の範囲から外れがちです（オフトピック気味です）。もし大きな不安があれば法律事務所など専門の機関に相談することを個人的にはオススメします。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2726/19110

Comment: 即逮捕となるかは分かりませんが、「mastodon 法律」辺りで検索してもらうと関連する情報がいくつか出てきますのでそちらを参照してみてください。

Comment: 適切な対応（削除、証拠の保全、場合によっては捜査機関への通報？）を行なっていれば正当に逮捕されることは無いはずです。
しかし、ホスティング業者にサーバーを落とされる事例は有ります。
違法な画像の投稿などの多くはそれを目的にしていると推測します。
つまり、投稿と同時にホスティング業者や捜査機関へ連絡してサーバーを落とさせて、サイト運営の継続を困難にする、ということです。
DDoS攻撃を受けた際も同じですが、ひたすら事なかれ主義のホスティング業者を選ぶと、実質的に運営は不可能になります。

Comment: おぉ恐ろしい、ありがとうございます。